# Circular Dependencies in MVP-Presenter beans (Vaadin)

Tags: spring, vaadin, mvp

I have a Vaadin MVP Architecture and for some time now I habe a problem with circular dependencies between Presenters.

I usually have a `show(...)` Method in my presenters, which will change the view, using the navigator, and use the parameters to show some data.

The problem is the more complex the application the the more I have circular calls between the Presenters.

```
A -> B.show(X)
B -> A.show(Y)
```

What is the best approach to hand over data to other presenters, without running into problems with circular dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

1. Use an event bus, so each presenter will fire events to unknown observers.
2. Use the Observer pattern together with mediators. For example A and B are presenters that need to notify each other. C is the mediator, e.g. a high-level presenter. C knows A and B, but A and B only know their observers. When A wants to notify B, it calls its observer C (the implementation of an A observer) and C then calls B. This way A and B are decoupled and the communication is encapsulated in C.

Here is an outline:

```
interface A {
    interface Observer {
        void onEventX(EventX event);
    }

    void setObserver(Observer o);

    void show(Data data);
}

// analog in B

class C implements A.Observer, B.Observer {
    private A a;
    private B b;

    public C(A a, B b){
        a.setObserver(this);
        b.setObserver(this);
    }

    @Override // overrides A's Observer
    public void onEvent(EventX event){
        b.show(event.getData());
    }
}
```